# Separating SystemVerilog nets before applying force

Tags: system-verilog, verification, hdl

I want to force a signal down a hierarchy from my testbench. The modules are automatically created from schematics (changing design is not possible), and they are mostly based on `wire` type.

A code example can be found on [EDA play ground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/nxNk).

```
//top level module
module dummy1(input A, output B);
  dummy2 u_dummy2(A, B);
  always @(A)
  begin
    assert (A == 1'b0) else $error("Force reached this level");
  end
endmodule

module dummy2(input A, output B);
  dummy3 u_dummy3(A, B);
endmodule

module dummy3(input A, output B);
    assign B  = A;  
endmodule
```

If I force `A` in `dummy3`, it will change `A` in `dummy2` and `dummy1` which is something expected. I want to know if there is a way to separate `A` in `dummy3` from `A` in `dummy2` so that force is not applied to top level module.

```
module dummy_tb;
    logic A, B;
  dummy1 u_dummy1(A, B); 
  initial
    begin
      A = 0;    
      $display("step0: A=%b B=%b", u_dummy1.A,u_dummy1.B);
      #1;
      //force A1 to 1
      force u_dummy1.u_dummy2.u_dummy3.A = 1'b1;
      #1;
      $display("step1: A=%b B=%b", u_dummy1.A,u_dummy1.B);
      release u_dummy1.u_dummy2.u_dummy3.A;
      #1;
      $display("step2: A=%b B=%b", u_dummy1.A,u_dummy1.B);
      //TODO: find something to separate A in u_dummy3 from A in u_dummy2, then force
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: Looks likea all simulators behave the same way, doing some port collapsing. You can force 'B' instead.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to "separate" the nets without a change to the Verilog source code for the design modules, but you could achieve a similar effect by also forcing `A` in `dummy2`:

```
  #1;
  //force A1 to 1
  force u_dummy1.u_dummy2.u_dummy3.A = 1'b1;
  force u_dummy1.u_dummy2.A = 1'b0; // <-------- add this line
  #1;
```

[edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/MnPv)

Comment: The addition of that line will force all the signals on the hierarchy to go low and overrides the first force. 
[Code example with your suggestion](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/B3ud)

Comment: @MohamedBekoucha: Why do you need to do this strange thing anyway?  Perhaps this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: the idea is to force some test pattern at an internal module instead of creating a test that will drive the IOs of the whole hierarchy. This is easier for me at this stage as the module being forced would require much more effort to test all its features if I take the usual approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this behavior results from a couple of quotes from the standard:

1. > **23.3.3 Port connection rules**:
   > Each port connection shall be a continuous assignment of source to sink, where one connected item shall be
   > a signal source and the other shall be a signal sink. The assignment shall be a continuous assignment from
   > source to sink for input or output ports.

This makes dummy3.A the sink and dummy_tb.A the source.

2. > **10.6.2 The force and release procedural statements**: A force procedural statement on a net shall override all drivers of the net—gate outputs, module outputs,
   > and continuous assignments—until a release procedural statement is executed on the net. When released,
   > the net shall immediately be assigned the value determined by the drivers of the net.

This makes dummy_tb.A a driver to the dummy3.A; So, basically verilog is forced to force all input ports on the way.

As a result, there is no way to do what you want without either forcing the port in the above level of hierarchy to a different value or to force outputs of continuous assignments in the low level module (force dummy3.B).